# Catch SIGSTOP with SIGKILL before gracefully

Tags: python, unix, signals

Unfortunately `SIGSTOP` cannot be catched. Is it common or good practice to send a `SIGTERM` to my process before, so I can gracefully shutdown my script? There is not enough time between the two, would I require a sleep of 1 second?

```
kill SIGSTOP pid
... kill child processes with stop and kill
kill SIGKILL pid
```

P.S. What is the difference between `SIGSTOP` and `SIGKILL`?

Comment: Why would you want to shutdown before `SIGSTOP`? The process can be restarted with `SIGCONT`.

Comment: Possibly you should be using `SIGTSTP` which *is* catchable, it's how TTY job control works.

Comment: Good point, I adjusted my question

Comment: `SIGSTOP` is for stopping a process temporarily, similar to typing `Ctl-z`. `SIGKILL` is for terminating a process completely.

Comment: `SIGSTOP` and `SIGTSTP` are similar, except that the latter can be caught, usually for the purpose of restoring terminal modes.

Comment: Your edit is incomplete. You changed the code to `SIGKILL`, but the title and text still refer to `SIGTERM`.

Comment: SIGSTOP is to SIGTSTP as SIGKILL is to SIGTERM.

Answer (score 3):

`SIGSTOP` is a misnomer for what it does. It *pauses* the execution of the process and cannot be caught. `SIGSTOP` is usually used with `SIGCONT`, which reverts what `SIGSTOP` does and makes your process continue to run again.

`SIGKILL` also cannot be caught since the reason this signal exist is that your process may hang because of your code. `SIGKILL` kills the process and hands over the memory allocated by the process to OS.

If you want to close some connections, release a memory area or do some clean up, you can use `SIGTERM` which can be caught by your process.

Comment: With which signals would you shutdown a Python script properly but with the possibility that it can clean up some stuff (for 1-2) seconds that otherwise wouldn't?

Comment: @DanielStephens `SIGTERM` is what you are looking for.

Comment: I sometimes see SIGTERM and SIGKILL sent right after another. Wouldn't I need a `sleep` command in-between to give the process 1-2 seconds?

Comment: Of course, you send `SIGTERM` first and give the process a couple of seconds or minutes(depending on the process) and then if it doesn't gracefully shut down, you send `SIGKILL`.